# Azure Network : Prevent subnet to subnet communication

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have the following subnets

1. Subnet_1 = 10.2.3.0
2. Subnet_1 = 10.2.4.0

I want to prevent subnet to subnet communication. As far as I see, it can be done using the Network Security Group. However I am not sure about the required change.

Comment: You can have a look into this - https://thesleepyadmins.com/2022/10/08/network-security-group-restrict-access-between-azure-subnets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to prevent communication between 2 Subnet**

I have created 2 subnets in my **Vnet**, like below.

**Subnet** 1: Prod-Subnet (10.0.1.0/24)

**Subnet** 2: default (10.0.0.0/24)

In order to prevent communication between both the VNet, you need to create an inbound and outbound rule in same NSG group, like below.

[image]

I have created 2 virtual machines and attached above subnets to 2 virtual machines, like below.

**Prod-subnet** attached to **VM1**
**Default** Subnet attached to **VM2**

[image]

Create inbound and outbound rule in **Network Security Group** to block the communicatioin ,like below.

**Inbound Rule:**

```
Source IP: 10.0.0.9/24
Source Port: * ( for all)
Destination IP: 10.0.1.0/24
Destination Port: *( for all)
Service: custom
```

> (Note: If you want block particular service and port, mention the port  details and protocol type)

[image]

**Outbound Rule:**

```
Source IP: 10.0.1.0/24
Source Port: * ( for all)
Destination IP: 10.0.0.0/24
Destination Port: *( for all)
Service: custom
```

[image]

Tested communication and its getting denied from the subnets.

**VM 1 Result**

[image]

**VM 2 Result**

[image]